# Get sum of objects elements (JSON file) dropped into a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, json, drag-and-drop

I'll be short about it.

What I want:

**1. Load json file** (optional, if I can work with loaded json content into the script tag directly into the page - see point (2))

**2. Load images** (along with stats) from json file into div1 (but only images are displayed) (kinda did it, I loaded the json content directly into a script tag)

**3. Drag & Drop images from div1 into div2** (with drag/drop function) (I know how)

**4. Check if indeed images are in div2.**

**if true**
Show stats (stats from json file annexed to images placed into div2) in div3.

**if not**
Dont show stats;

Img layout: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbn3M.jpg)

JSON content: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPiq0.jpg)

Comment: You can load the json by putting it into a script tag and getting its `innerHTML` by doing `document.getElementById()`, use `fetch()`, or `XMLhttpRequest`. Check the files by doing `filename.split(".")[-1]==="png"||filename.split(".")[-1]==="jpg"` and then check by getting the innerHTML of the div2 after dragging and make sure it has as many `/`s as pictures (each `/` is for a tag `<tag></tag>` ) since it has to have that many end tags.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.